# How to not initialize ssh session

Tags: ssh

Well I was smart enough to put an `exit 0` in one of my dotfiles on a remote machine. Whenever I log in, the shell exits instantly now. How can I ssh into a machine without sourcing all the dot files?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround to solve this problem by directly running a command:

```sh
ssh -t remotehost vim /dotfile/i/had/to/revert
```